# Method Array Sum

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, indexing

Hi guys I got a small problem for some reason I got an error on my sum. and however and where ever I put my int sum; it wont fix the error.

```
static void TotalOfEvenNegatives(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && array[i] < 0)
        {
            int sum;
            sum += array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should probably return the sum too

Comment: How about `return array.Where(x => x % 2 == 0 && x < 0).Sum();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void TotalOfEvenNegatives(int[] array)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && array[i] < 0)
        {

            sum += array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

You need to initialise it outside the loop and set it to 0. By setting it inside the loop, you are overriding it every iteration so it can never increment.

Comment: Oh I had to set it to 0 I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `sum` inside your loop, thus overwriting all the values, declare it outside.

```
static int TotalOfEvenNegatives(int[] array)
{
    int sum = 0; //HERE

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && array[i] < 0)
        {
            sum += array[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Also your method should return `sum` and you can use it like:

```
int total = TotalOfEvenNegatives(new [] {1,2,3,4,}; //ClassName.TotalOfEvenNegatives
```

Do not forget to initialize the `sum` with `0` otherwise you will get the error "Use of unassigned variable"

Comment: I did try to declare it outside but it still gives me the same problem.

Comment: @TheBoringGuy, assign it `0` at the time of declaration, otherwise you will end up with error "Use of unassigned variable"

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it the simple way:

```
      int[] myArray = {1,2,3,4,} ;
      int   sum     = myArray.Where( x => x < 0 && 0 == x % 2 ).Sum() ;
```

Comment: its nice but I  don't like to use something I haven't learned yet :)